# Advantages of mia_material over mia_material_x and _passes

Tags: 3d, rendering, maya, 3dsmax

Mental ray's mia_material is useful, but in order to use bump mapping you need to upgrade it to a mia_material_x, and in order to have it work with render passes you need to upgrade it to a mia_material_x_passes.

But why not remove mia_material and _x altogether and simply use the _passes one, since it can do everything the other two can as well? Are there some advantages to the other two? Is it simply for backward compatibility?

Comment: It's mostly a question which the owners/decision makers of Mental Ray could answer *precisely*.

Comment: Not a question for SO, please use the CGSOCIETY forums or Autodesks forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily, it seems to be backward compatibility. Users don't want nodes created and saved from an older version of Maya or 3dsmax to complain of `Unknown node` when opened in a newer version because the developer of Mental ray decided to drop it which would in turn create annoyed users.

Secondly, it provides user's with a variety of choices (technically a software with more features) to choose from. Why use a butcher's knife when a kitchen knife would do? The `mia_material_x_passes` node would definitely have an extra cost (computing resources) given it's extra features.

Comment: Theres really no extra cost in speed, just extra cost in memory consumption, and disk writing operations. But if you dont dump the pass then no extra cost. So in 99% of cases the difference is negligible. Thats kind of the point with passes rendering being rolled into the core. Backwards compatibility being the only reason. Not sure tough this is a good question for Slashdot.